# Can I see what exactly each stash entry contains?

Tags: git, version-control, git-stash

When I do `git stash` I usually don't remember what I have saved after a while and when doing `git stash list` the output does not help.
Is there a way to see the actual contents of each stashed entry? Like when we do `git show`?

Answer (score 3):

```
git stash show -p [<stash>]
```

will show the diff for a stash.

Comment: @janos:Thanks for the clarification. I didn't know what [<stash>] meant

Comment: Note that `git stash show -p` diffs the work-tree commit against its base commit (equivalent of `git diff stash^ stash`, or add `--stat` if you omit `-p` on `show`).  To see what's in the index, use `git diff stash^ stash^2`.